# How to make CMake find google protobuf on windows?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I am using Google Protobuf with CMake. On Linux the Protobuf library is found by:

```
find_package( Protobuf REQUIRED )
```

CMake knows where to look for the library. How though do I get this to work in Windows? Is there an environment variable I should create, such as `PROTOBUF_LIB`? I have looked in `FindProtobuf.cmake` but cannot work out what is required.

Answer (score 8):

I also struggled with this. To be more clear.

On Windows (7, similar on older windows):
Start → Control Panel → System → Advanced System Settings → Environment Variables

Then either on the top panel or the bottom panel (if you want it to apply to other users do it on the bottom), create two new variables. The 1st one is

- CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH which points at the bottom of your include path (should contain a "google" folder)
- CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH which should contain "libprotobuf" "libprotobuf-lite" "liteprotoc" .lib files.

After you create the variables press OK and then re-start cmake (or clean the cache).

Answer (score 6):

Newest [protobuf v3](https://github.com/google/protobuf) have CMake support out of the box.

You could use protobuf repository as submodule and just use

```
add_subdiretory("third-party/protobuf/cmake")
```

to get all protobuf targets.
Then you can add dependency to protobuf with

```
target_link_libraries(YourLibrary libprotobuf libprotobuf-lite libprotoc)
```

**Another** possible way is available. With protobuf's CMake configuration you can build and install protobuf binaries once and use them across several projects in your development:

```
git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
mkdir protobuf\tmp
cd protobuf\tmp
cmake ..\cmake
cmake --build .
cmake --build . --target install
```

Then you can use `find_package` with hint paths like

```
find_package(protobuf REQUIRED
    HINTS
       "C:/Program Files/protobuf"
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/protobuf")
if (NOT PROTOBUF_FOUND)
    message("protobuf not found")
    return()
endif()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Protobuf on windows calls find_library which will search your PATH and LIB variables.

Comment: Thanks, I have since discovered that find_library also searches CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH, CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH and CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to use protobuf v2 with cmake on Windows and build it with your project settings. Please, try look to [cmake-external-packages project](https://github.com/halex2005/cmake-external-packages) and [protobuf-v2 CMakeLists](https://github.com/halex2005/cmake-external-packages/blob/master/protobuf-v2/CMakeLists.txt) which do the job.
In fact, I wrote it because `ExternalProject_Add` is wrong (because does stuff in build phase instead of generation phase).

This CMakeLists.txt will download protobuf from [protobuf's github releases](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases?after=v3.0.0-alpha-1), extract, and emit cmake targets which you should add reference to with `target_link_libraries`.

Use [git-subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/), [git-submodule](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2011/12/git-submodules/) or just copy this repository contents to your repository subfolder.

Then add packages you want to use with `add_subdiretory`. For protobuf, use:

```
add_subdirectory(path/to/cmake-external-packages/protobuf-v2)
```

Protobuf's includes will be copied to `path/to/cmake-external-packages/include` folder. You can customize its location in your top-level CMakeLists:

```
set (EXTERNAL_PACKAGES_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/third-party/include
    CACHE STRING "Directory for third-party include files, where include folders will be copied")
include_directories(${EXTERNAL_PACKAGES_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Just reference protobuf for your executable:

```
add_executable(your_exe ${your_exe_sources})
target_link_libraries(your_exe libprotobuf libprotobuf-lite libprotoc)
```

Hope this helps.